Identify a BBC period drama/Masterpiece Theater movie?
I remember a clip from some English film(late 90's or early 2000's) shown on Masterpiece Theater when I was a child and I still haven't been able to find what it was.
It seemed like a brother and sister dressed in period clothing were being reunited after some sort of hardship. The brother rows up in a rowboat as the land seems to be flooded and stops at a house where his sister is about to jump into his waiting boat. Unfortunately, once she does so her foot gets caught in some of the rope that he had thrown to her and she drowns. Out of his angst the brother drowns himself too. 
Can anyone help identify this film? Not sure if i imagined all of this and I remember it must have been broadcast on Masterpiece Theater/PBS if that helps at all. 

Sounds very much like the end of the 1997 Masterpiece Theatre production of The Mill on the Floss with Emily Watson, but I think you got the roles mixed up. In the end:

A great storm causes the river to break its banks, and during the course of it Maggie courageously rescues Tom from the mill [in a rowboat].

But Tom gets tangled in a rope and drowns; his sister jumps in to save him and dies with him.

